Using DebugFS with Strings in the Linux Kernel
I am developing a Linux kernel module which uses DebugFS to read some values from files in userspace into kernel space.
So far, I have my DebugFS directory at /sys/kernel/debug/example. This directory contains a set of files bound to u32_t variables. I can read values from these files and assign them to u32_t variables in my kernel module.
I want to read some ASCII characters from a DebugFS file and assign it to a char[] of arbitrary length. However (as far as I have seen), the DebugFS documentation does not contain any functions specifically for this purpose.
Current code creates the file "example" at /sys/kernel/debug/ and binds hello to whatever unsigned 32-bit integer is in that file:

static u32 hello = 0;

int init_module(void)
{
    struct dentry *junk;

    dir = debugfs_create_dir("example", 0);
    if (!dir) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create /sys/kernel/debug/example\n");
        return -1;
    }

    junk = debugfs_create_u32("hello", 0666, dir, &hello);
    if (!junk) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create /sys/kernel/debug/example/hello\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    debugfs_remove_recursive(dir);
}


You can either create a binary blob containing your string, or create a file and implement read and write operations on it.

Thanks, I was able to create a file and implement those operations following https://janczer.github.io/create-simple-debugfs-object/ but I'm not sure how to get the string from the file (that example only writes to/reads from the file from the terminal, not in code).

Side note: You are not supposed to check the errors from debugfs APIs, they has to work without those. The rare exception is when the code is solely debugfs related one.

Solved. Refer to the link I put in the comments (https://janczer.github.io/create-simple-debugfs-object/), the content in the file "data_file" is assigned to char data[].
